# Observer is deprecated in Java 9. What should we use instead of it?

Tags: java, java-8, deprecated, observer-pattern, java-9

Java 9 came out, and [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) has been deprecated.
Why is that? Does it mean that we shouldn't implement observer pattern anymore?

It would be good to know what is a better alternative?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**Why is that? Does it mean that we shouldn't implement observer pattern anymore?**

Answering the latter part first -

***YES***, it does mean you shouldn't implement `Observer` and `Obervable`s anymore.

[Why were they deprecated](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801) -

They didn't provide a rich enough event model for applications. For example, they could support only the notion that something has changed, but didn't convey any information about what has changed.

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8034790/1746118) puts it nicely upfront that *`Observer` has a weakness: all `Observable`s are the same*. You have to implement the logic that is based on `instanceof` and cast object to concrete type into `update()` method of the `Observer` implementation.

To add to it there were bugs like one [could not serialize the `Observable`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4180466) class because as it didn't implement `Serializable` interface and all of its members were private.

**What is a better alternative to that?**

On the other hand `Listeners` have a lot of types and they have callback methods and don't require casting. As pointed by @Ravi in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380252/1746118) you can make use of  [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) instead.

For the rest of it the `@Deprecation` has been marked with proper documentation to explore other packages as linked in other answers as well.

---

Note that the deprecation was also marked with an analysis as stated in [this mail](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040473.html)  -

> These days, anyone encountering these is probably hitting them by
> mistake while using `RxJava` or other reactive-stream frameworks. In
> which case, users will normally want to instead use the jdk9
> `java.util.concurrent.Flow` APIs that all reactive-streams frameworks
> should be compatible/interoperable within their planned upcoming
> jdk9-compatible versions.

***Edit***: It's also worth mentioning that the deprecation of the APIs is not primarily just because of the above reason, but also being unable to maintain such legacy code as mentioned in comments of a few of the bug reports (linked above) which were raised to mark an improvement in its implementation in one or another way.

Comment: +1. Good answer, though I am still trying to understand it. Is Observer in Java deprecated because of some inherent problem of the design pattern itself (as defined in the book by GOF) or the problem of the support for the pattern by Java? In other OO languages, such as C#, C++, Python, does the observer design pattern also have the same problem as in Java?

Comment: The fact that a particular implementation is deprecated doesn't mean that the Observer *pattern* is fatally flawed. `Listener` is also an Observer.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, couldn' t agree more, one of the main reasons to deprecate the API is also the maintenance attached to it and that changing its implementation could have been breaking other code.

Comment: @curious95 Not able to understand *way of notifying concurrent* there.

Comment: @nullpointer when I call notifyObservers() function. All of my added observers start to update. Is this happening concurrently (multi-threading)?

Comment: @curious95 Yes calling `notifyObservers()` is concurrent. Here is a [codelet](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4212311) from the same shared to explain its functionality in details.

Comment: But, what if you don't have a property that changes? Would we not misuse the `PropertyChangeListener` by creating pseudo properties?

Answer (score 49):

There are more reasons :

**[Not Serializable](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4180466)** - Since, Observable doesn't implements Serializable. So, you can't Serialize Observable neither its subclass.

**[No Thread Safety](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025077)** - The methods can be overridden by its subclasses, and event notification can occur in different orders and possibly on different threads, which is enough to disrupt any "thread safety".

**[Less to offer](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801)** -

> They don't provide a rich enough event model for applications. For
> example, they support only the notion that something has changed, but
> they don't convey any information about what has changed

**Open Issues** - As mentioned, there were lot of major issues raised (thread safety, Serializable) and most of them had complexities to fix and still "not fixed" or **No Active Development**, and that is the reason why it has been **deprecated**.

I would also recommend to read this answer [Why should the observer pattern be deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632412/1162620), @Jeff has explained other reasons for deprecation.

---

### So, what's the alternative we have ?

You can use **[`PropertyChangeEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html)** and **[`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)** from **[`java.beans`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html)** package.

Comment: `PropertyChangeListener` replaces `Observer`, but what should I extend/implement in place of `Observable`?

Comment: Update: I think the approach is to add a `PropertyChangeSupport` as an instance variable, but I'd appreciate a confirmation.

Comment: @LastStar007 I think you're right. I found a code sample on [Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern) that does just that.

Comment: This gives a good summary of why not to use Observer & Observable.

Comment: Ravi can you please add an example for PropertyChange alternative? Dragos Stanciu gave a valuable one.

Comment: @LastStar007 But what if I don't have an property that changed?

Answer (score 25):

> Why Observer is deprecated in Java 9?

**Ans:** The `Observable` class and the `Observer` interface have been deprecated in Java 9 because the event model supported by `Observer` and `Observable` is quite limited, the order of notifications delivered by `Observable` is unspecified, and state changes are not in one-for-one correspondence with notifications.

See Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

> Alternate of Observer pattern?

There are many alternatives of Observer design pattern and Reactive Streams is one of them.

**Reactive Streams or Flow API**:

`Flow` is a class introduced in Java 9 and has 4 interrelated interfaces : `Processor`, `Publisher`, `Subscriber` and `Subscription`.

`Flow.Processor`   : A component that acts as both a Subscriber and Publisher.

`Flow.Publisher`   : A producer of items received by Subscribers.

`Flow.Subscriber`  : A receiver of messages.

`Flow.Subscription`: Message control linking a `Flow.Publisher` and `Flow.Subscriber`.

See Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html

Answer (score 12):

Considering that the `Observable` class and the `Observer` interface have been deprecated as of Java 9. As per the post [Java's Observer and Observable Are Deprecated in JDK 9](https://dzone.com/articles/javas-observer-and-observable-are-deprecated-in-jd)

> The event model supported by Observer and Observable is quite limited,
>   the order of notifications delivered by Observable is unspecified, and
>   state changes are not in one-for-one correspondence with
>   notifications.
>   For a richer event model, consider using the **[`java.beans`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html)**
>   package. For reliable and ordered messaging among threads, consider
>   using one of the concurrent data structures in the
>   **[`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)** package. For reactive streams style programming, see the Flow API.

Answer (score -1):

Also is possible to use CDi 2.0 , [Event Handling](http://Event%20Handling)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

The problem is with buggy Java implementations of Java class/interface named Observer, Observable etc. - but not with GoF Observer Pattern.

Comment: why the answer? the question has already been answered in detail with lots of different views taken into account?

Comment: That is not the answer to the question **„What should we use instead of it?“**.