# How can I enable / disable a Jbutton like this?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I have a case like this:
[image]

I have a `JFrame`, let's call it `frame1`. There's a `JButton` named `Submit` in `frame1.`

Inside the `frame1`, there is a `JPanel`, call it `panel1`.  There's a `JTextField` in that `JPanel`.

The `frame1` and `panel1` are two different Java files.

I want to do something like this:

When I user edit, delete or insert the `JTextField`, there's a `DocumentListerner` to check if the input match with a `regex`. If it matches, then the `Submit` button is enabled, otherwise the `Submit` button is disabled.

I already know how to implement the `DocumentListener` on `JTextField1` with `regex` check. The thing I don't know how to do is to make the `frame1` listen to the boolean outcome of that `regex` check, so the `Submit` button will be enabled/disabled.

Could anyone help please ?

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could be to have the `JButton` on the same class as the `JTextField`, for a simple GUI as the one you have this is doable.

But we know there are times that this isn't possible so another way that you could have this done [up to Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46380073/2180785) is using the `Observer` pattern, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744450/when-should-we-use-observer-and-observable). After Java 9, `Observer` and `Observable` are deprecated so you should use **[`PropertyChangeEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html)** and **[`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)** from **[`java.beans`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html)** package<sup>1</sup>.

So, if you're not using Java 9 or higher and don't care about the caveats of `Observer` and `Observable` then you could have a sample code like this one:

**EnableButtonInOtherClass**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class EnableButtonInOtherClass implements Observer {
    private JFrame frame;
    private OtherClass pane;
    private JButton button;
    private ObservableField observableField;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new EnableButtonInOtherClass()::createAndShowGUI);
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        
        observableField = new ObservableField();
        observableField.addObserver(this);
        
        pane = new OtherClass(observableField);
        button = new JButton("Click me!");
        
        button.setEnabled(false);
        
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Text is a digit: " + arg);
        button.setEnabled((boolean) arg);
    }
}
```

**OtherClass**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OtherClass extends JPanel implements DocumentListener {
    private JTextField field;
    private ObservableField observableField;
    
    public OtherClass(ObservableField observableField) {
        field = new JTextField(10);
        
        add(field);
        this.observableField = observableField;
        
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateState();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateState();
    }
    
    private void updateState() {
        String patternString = "[0-9]+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(field.getText());
        observableField.updateState(matcher.matches());
    }
}
```

**ObservableField**

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class ObservableField extends Observable {
    public void updateState(boolean state) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(state);
    }
}
```

The above example makes use of the `ObservableField` class to handle the `Observable` class, that has an update method that notifies the observers (`EnableButtonInOtherClass`) that there has been a change every time you type into the `JTextField` on `OtherClass` and based on the `matcher.matches()` value determines if the `JButton` should be enabled or not.

But again, for a simple UI as the one you have it's easier to move the `JButton` to the same file and / or on `JButton`'s `ActionListener` evaluate what's inside the `JTextField` rather than enable / disable the `JButton`.

Here are some screenshots of how the program looks like.

[image] [image] [image]

<sup>1</sup><sub>Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380252/2180785)</sub>