# Java built-in Observable push notifications

Tags: java, design-patterns, observable

**UPDATE** Added the full code to make it easier to understand.

I am trying to understand how to implement push vs pull notifications using Java built-in Observer.

the `Observable` class has 2 methods `notifyObservers()` and  `notifyObservers(Object arg)`

according to the docs:
Each observer has its `update` method called with two arguments: this observable object and the `arg` argument.

here is my Observer class

```java
public class CurrentConditionsDisplay implements Observer, DisplayElement {
    private float temperature;
    private float humidity;
    private Observable observable;

    public CurrentConditionsDisplay(Observable observable) {
        this.observable = observable;
        observable.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Current conditions: " + temperature + "F degrees and "
                + humidity + "% humidity");
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        /*
        if (o instanceof WeatherData) {
            WeatherData weatherData = (WeatherData) o;
            this.temperature = weatherData.getTemperature();
            this.humidity = weatherData.getHumidity();
        }*/

        if (arg instanceof WeatherData) {
        WeatherData weatherData = (WeatherData) arg;
        this.temperature = weatherData.getTemperature();
        this.humidity = weatherData.getHumidity();
        }

        display();
    }
```

and  in my observable class

```java
public class WeatherData extends Observable {
    private float temperature;
    private float humidity;
    private float pressure;

    private void measurementsChanged() {
        setChanged();
        //notifyObservers();
        notifyObservers(this);
    }

    public void setMeasurements(float temperature, float humidity, float pressure) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        measurementsChanged();
    }

    public float getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public float getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public float getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }
```

I've tried both methods, and both objects can be cast down to WeatherData(the Observer) and then get the data from them.

using both methods seem like push notification-type for me, so what is the difference?
and how can I implement pull notification-type using it?

Comment: Did you read that [Observer is deprecated in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380073/observer-is-deprecated-in-java-9-what-should-we-use-instead-of-it)?

Comment: I just read it. I am reading head first design pattern and it said that using this built-in pattern. I can choose to get push or pull notifications and I couldn't understand how to do so.

Comment: pulling == polling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of notifyObservers()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers()):

> Each observer has its update method called with two arguments: this observable object and `null`. In other words, this method is equivalent to: `notifyObservers(null)`

That means that you should never call `notifyObservers(this)`—it’s redundant.  Normally, the argument would be additional data about the change event.  This is analogous to more modern event listener classes ([Observable and Observer are now deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html)) whose events contain data in addition to the event source.  For example, if you add an ActionListener to a button, pressing the button at runtime causes the ActionListener’s `actionPerformed` method to be called with an event that contains data such as the time when the action occurred.

A pull notification isn’t really a notification at all.  Pulling means you don’t wait to be told that something changed;  you ask whether anything has happened.

An example of this would be keeping a boolean field in your class that indicates whether any changes have occurred:

```
public class WeatherData {
    private boolean changed;

    // (other fields)

    public boolean checkForChanges() {
        boolean hasChanged = changed;
        // Now that someone has checked, reset the change flag
        changed = false;
        return hasChanged;
    }

    private void measurementsChanged() {
        changed = true;
        // Nothing else to do here.  Caller must "pull" (request) the
        // new state, by calling checkForChanges.
    }
```

As for how to do the pulling, just keep a reference to a WeatherData object in your CurrentConditionsDisplay class, and check whether it has changed:

```
public class CurrentConditionsDisplay implements DisplayElement { 

    private final WeatherData weatherData;

    public CurrentConditionsDisplay(WeatherData observable) {
        this.weatherData = observable;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        // This is the pull.
        if (weatherData.checkForChanges()) {
            this.temperature = weatherData.getTemperature();
            this.humidity = weatherData.getHumidity();
        }

        System.out.println("Current conditions: " + temperature + "F degrees and "
                + humidity + "% humidity");
    }
```