# How to observe different attributes of same types with the Observer pattern?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I implemented the Observer pattern in an MVC application so a bean can listen for changes in the model. Since I'm in Java8 I'm using Observer and Observable from Java.util. Here's part of what I coded:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class UserBean implements Observer{
   private Integer userId;
   private String userName;
   private String userEmail;
   /* getters and setters */
  
   @Override
   public void update(Observable o, Object object) {
       if(object instanceof Integer)
           setUserId((Integer)object);
       else if(object instanceof String)
           setUserName((String)object);
   }
}

public class UserModel extends Observable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    /* getters */
    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(id);
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(name);
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.name = email;
        // how can i listen for this change?
        /*setChanged();
        notifyObservers(email);*/
    }
}
```

I think the implementation is correct because, in a simple test that I made, the changes to Ids and Names are correctly read by the bean class, but I realized that I can't listen for changes of the email attributes because in the bean class I'm using 'instanceof' to understand which value I have to update.

There's a way to recognize which variable has changed? I should implement my own version of the Observer and Observable classes instead of using Java.Util?
I think that with the second solution I could define an update method for every attribute but I don't know how to manage the synchronization process in Java.

Comment: you can also notify the observer using a DTO which brings some extra info about the attribute

Comment: Don't use j.u.Observer and Observable. They are terribly outdated. A proper interface definition should make use of generics; they were written before generics existed.

Comment: following @Michael advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380073/observer-is-deprecated-in-java-9-what-should-we-use-instead-of-it

Comment: @fantaghirocco Oh, nice. I almost said in my last comment that they should go ahead and deprecate it already. Glad they have. That one passed me by :)

Comment: @fantaghirocco could you explain better? My professor doesn't explain to us all the existing patterns and I don't know DTO (I just google it).

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I know they are deprecated that's why I specified that I'm using Java8. This project is just a didactic project and I don't need to go further than Java8. Using the solution linked by fantaghiricco I could resolve my problem?

Comment: @AndreaEfficace The reasons they were deprecated in Java 9 are still applicable to Java 8, 7, 6, 5... Java 9 just happens to be the point when the JDK authors decided to publicly declare "don't use this any more".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in the `update` method is an `Observable`. That is your `UserModel` object that has changed, so it contains all the updated data. So instead of using the second parameter to pass the new *value* of an object you can use it to pass the *name* of the object that has changed (or use an `enum` because it's a bit *cleaner*).

A solution could look like this:

**UserBean:**

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import observer.UserModel.ChangedValue;

public class UserBean implements Observer {
    
    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    /* getters and setters */
    
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object object) {
        if (o instanceof UserModel && object instanceof ChangedValue) {
            UserModel userModel = (UserModel) o;
            ChangedValue changed = (ChangedValue) object;
            
            switch (changed) {
                case EMAIL:
                    setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
                    break;
                case ID:
                    setUserId(userModel.getId());
                    break;
                case NAME:
                    setUserName(userModel.getName());
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected ChangedValue type: " + changed);
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    //...
}
```

**UserModel:**

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class UserModel extends Observable {
    
    public enum ChangedValue {
        ID, //
        NAME, //
        EMAIL, //
        //...
    }
    
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
    //...
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(ChangedValue.ID);//use the enum types as parameters here
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(ChangedValue.NAME);
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.name = email;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(ChangedValue.EMAIL);
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** Like mentioned in the comments a generic approach would be better, to avoid the object casts. It could be used similar to this implementation. Just add some generic parameters, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: your approach is cleaner since there are no extra classes involved. Upvoted

Answer (score 2):

I mean something like this:

```
public class UserModel extends Observable {
    
    enum AttributeKind {
        ID, NAME, EMAIL;
    }
    
    class UserModelDescriptor {
        public AttributeKind attributeKind;
        public Object attribute;
        
        public UserModelDescriptor(AttributeKind attributeKind, Object attribute) {
            super();
            this.attributeKind = attributeKind;
            this.attribute = attribute;
        }
    }

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    /* getters */
    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(new UserModelDescriptor(AttributeKind.ID, id));
    }
        . . .
}
```

The observer:

```
public class UserBean implements Observer{

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        UserModelDescriptor descriptor = (UserModelDescriptor)arg;
        
        switch (descriptor.attributeKind) {
            case ID:
                int id = (Integer)descriptor.attribute;
                break;
                . . .
        }
    }
}
```

… but an approach based on the [PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) class is far better.

Comment: Oh, nice, I understand what you did here. I usually do something like this in C programming when I have to send complex data to threads. I think this should work, I'll give a try!

Comment: it's not that nice but it's possible: yes, the class usage reminds a C struct somehow